# Сформировать запрос на SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony3, doctrine2

У меня есть стандартный запрос вида для  для KNPpaginator

```
$category = $em->getRepository('WoolfBundle:Category')
        ->find($categoryId);
```

А как мне это сделать через SQL запрос по типу

`$dql   = "SELECT post FROM WoolfBundle:Category category WHERE category.id = $categoryId";`

Comment: "SELECT post" поле post находится все в тойже таблице категорий?

Comment: Да, в entity Category есть поле пост с OneToMany соотношением

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = $em->getRepository('WoolfBundle:Category')->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c.post')
    ->where('category.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $categoryId)
    ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult()
;
```